# Where can I see all my votes across the entire Stack Exchange network?

Tags: feature-request, support, voting, recent-activity

Sometimes, when searching for a post I voted on before, I find it hard to locate the exact stack it belonged.

I do know I can favorite those questions and have it showed in my SE activity page but that's not exactly what I want.

Is there any way to see my voting activity across all the Stack Exchange sites? Can this functionality be added if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Currently, this doesn't appear to be possible.

Comment: Also, not sure about downvotes there; that'd be a pretty useful feature.

Comment: Thanks @nicael for your edits and comments. Those are my thoughts too.

Comment: I take it you know how to view it per site?

Comment: @Tim Yes! It's just that I can't remember which site it was.

Comment: Other than SO, you have a negligible # of votes, how hard can it be to remember which site is which?  Also, keeping track of questions by whether or not you voted for them is not scalable, e.g. it would be less than useless for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I suppose you could but when you are an active user, the new feature might be too much for the system too handle...

This is not currently implemented as a feature as it cannot be seen in your SE profile. Of course, a new tab called Votes could be added to the [Activity](https://stackexchange.com/users/5046588/pythonmaster?tab=activity) tab and will continue to sync all the votes as fast as possible. For heavy voters, you might want to blame the slow speed on caching... Anyways, this could be implied though its usability is debatable.

Comment: Thanks PythonMaster. Your answer makes quite some sense to me.